# Where in Visual Studio 2012 did Page Controls and Events goto for codebehind?

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2012, code-behind, web-controls

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do something that I did forever in VS2008 and earlier with VS 2012.

When creating a web application, throw some server side controls on the page, then goto the codebehind and at the top of the code editor were 2 dropdowns.  The one on the left displayed the page and controls on the page, selecting one of them say a GridView, would then display the Events for that control in the right side dropdown.  So I could double click on it and create one of the events without remembering and typing the event in code.

In my VS 2012, the left only displays the Page (big help) and no controls.  With that selected, the right dropdown displays controls, but selecting it only loads up the designer for that page and the entry for that control.

Is it a setting I don't have set, or how and why is this changed, how can do this again in VS2012?

Comment: This doesn't seem very nice if this is the case - i've yet to use 2012, but if they removed this feature i'll definately avoid using it!

Comment: From what I have found you actually have to go to the design view of your .aspx page click on a control then go to properties in order to view events etc.  Not fond of this at all, very displeased with this and all of my coworkers agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the properties window, but you have to click on the lightning bolt icon.

Comment: I finally found that section because of creating some Window apps. Makes no sense to me why they removed it from the codebehind editor. I tend to be a creature of habit and found it quite convient where it was. Now I have to flip back and forth or remember how to type it in manually.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: For page level events you may need to use the "View Component Designer" option as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1046360

Answer (score 2):

You can re-enable the events navigation bar at the top of code behind files like this:

1) From the **Tools** menu select **Options**

2) From the options on the left select **All Languages**

3) From the options on the right, click the checkbox next to **Navigation Bar** then check it again.

It is important to switch it off then back on again.

This will override your development environment settings and will force the Event Navigation Bar to appear at the top of all text editors.

Answer (score 0):

Double-click on control (button) in Design vew to create a handler for its Click event.